# If/Then statement in SAS

Tags: database, sas

thanks for taking time to help me out.

Basically, I would like to generate a random number from 0 to 1, 15,000 times and if the generated value is below .25, then I would like it to display 0 in that spot in the table. If it is greater than .25, I would like to keep the original value.

Any tips on what I should use in the asterik part? The code is pasted below in the format I used:

```
data rand_data;
call streaminit(123);

do i = 1 to 15000;
    u = rand('Uniform');
   ***if u < .25 then do;
    0 
   else*** 
   output;
   end;
   run; 
proc print data= rand_data;
run;
```

Comment: If you're not a statistician I would consult with one about the resulting distribution, as I'm not sure it would qualify as very random.  Even the newer distribution with RAND can lose some of its apparent randomness when you do things like this.  If you're just trying to get a distribution over [0.25,1) then there are better ways to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to replace values that are less than 0.25 with 0.

```
if u < 0.25 then u=0;
output;
```

If instead you want to ignore the values that are less than 0.25 then make the OUTPUT statement conditional.

```
if u >= 0.25 then output;
```

Given your code structure this could result in less than 15,000 observations.

Comment: Thank you so much! I needed the output to still show 0. Life saver!!